# Refresh Page when logging in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router, frontend

I currently have built a functional login page. Once logged in,I am grabbing data with componentDidmount() to parse for user info (name, etc.)

When logging in, I'm currently using Redirect from the react-router; however, this will not refresh the page.

What's the best way to not use Redirect and reload the page once logging in? This way my info can be fetched from componentDidMount().

I also used ComponentWillReceieveProps but it also won't fit what I need for the code

Thanks!

Attempt:

```
From Login.js

const { error, loading, token } = this.props;
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    if (token) {
      return <Redirect to="/home" />
    }


from ArticleView.js:

    axios.get('...') {
    ...
    }



  from Forms2.js:


componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
       console.log(newProps)
       if (newProps.token !== this.props.token) {
         authAxios.get("user")
         .then(res =>{
           this.setState({id: res.data.id});
           this.setState({username:res.data.username});
         });
       }
       console.log(newProps.token)
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

Why change the entire Component flow instead of picking up the right life cycle method?

By the way `ComponentWillReceieveProps()` is soon to be deprecated if not already deprecated, since it was giving too many headaches for the React team. It's been replaced with static method - `getDerivedStateFromProps()`.

Small difference between this and `ComponentWillReceieveProps()` is that being a static method you won't be able to use `this`.

Read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).

I tried converting your component to use `getDerivedStateFromProps()`. But there were too many complications since `this`, `prevProps` and `async/await` can't be used in it.

Simpler solution would be to use React Hooks

```
const Login = ({ error, loading, token }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState();
  const [id, setId] = React.useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    authAxios.get("user")
      .then(res =>{
        setId(res.data.id);
        setUsername(res.data.username);
      });
   }, [token]) 
// UseEffect hooks will run if React detects
// changes in props.token
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: With getDerviedStatefromProps, I still can't get the data only after I reload the page

Comment: Yes, perhaps post what you have tried with `ComponentWillReceieveProps()`.

Comment: Right now, the token is correctly passed in and in the render method it still does not reload the page when going to '/hom'

Comment: I've just updated my post wit the component will receive props. From Login.js it will be redirected to /home which goes to Forms2.js. It will only work when I refresh the page

Comment: Thanks for the help Vijay. Unfortunently, I just implemented my login and  with react hooks and it didn't work. Do you have any idea on using javascript to reload the page the first time when hitting the page?